# Find all ids not exist in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a tables as below :

```
#Groups
Group_ids
1,2
3,4
5,6

#Test
Id   Date
1     1/1/2022
5     2/1/2022

Result
Group_ids
3,4
```

Only 3,4 group should be selected since all ids in this group does not exist in the #test table.

```
Create table #groups(group_ids varchar(200))
insert into #groups('1,2', '3,4', '5,6')

create table #test(id int, test_date datetime)
insert into #test values (1, '1/1/2022'), (5, '2/1/2022')
```

I've tried

```
select *
from #groups g
cross apply
( select 
count(t.test_date) over (partition by t.id) as 'test_ids_count',
count(g.value) over (partition by g.value) as 'ids_total'
from string_split(g.group_ids) g
left outer join #test t on g.value = t.id
where g.id is null)sy
where sy.test_ids_count = sy.ids_total
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: DDL, Insert statements, sample sql, desired output everything is there in the post.

Comment: Just try to run it in SSMS. It fails on syntax. #4 is completely missing.

Comment: I *really* recommend fixing your design and normalising your data; delimited data breaks fundamental normalisation rules and quickly makes things difficult. "Simple" tasks like foreign keys are impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your Create query have syntax errors, here's the corrected query with the desired result:

```
drop table if exists #groups,#test
Create table #groups(group_ids varchar(200))
insert into #groups VALUES ('1,2')
insert into #groups VALUES ('3,4')
insert into #groups VALUES ('5,6')

create table #test(id int, test_date datetime)
insert into #test values (1, '1/1/2022')
insert into #test values (5, '2/1/2022')


SELECT *
FROM #groups g
WHERE group_ids NOT IN (
                            SELECT group_ids
                            FROM #groups g
                            CROSS APPLY string_split(g.group_ids,',') ss
                            LEFT JOIN #test t on t.id = ss.value
                            WHERE t.id IS NOT NULL
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XQuery Quantified Expression.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @groups table (group_ids varchar(200));
insert @groups (group_ids) VALUES
('1,2'), 
('3,4'), 
('5,6');

DECLARE @test table (id int, test_date datetime);
insert @test values 
(1, '1/1/2022'), 
(5, '2/1/2022');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

-- XQuery Quantified Expressions
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
       , c.value('some $r in /root/r/text()
            satisfies $r = sql:column("tst.id")', 'BIT') AS result
    FROM @groups AS t
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
              REPLACE(group_ids, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
             ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
    CROSS JOIN @test AS tst
)
SELECT group_ids
FROM rs
GROUP BY group_ids
HAVING SUM(CAST(result AS INT)) = 0;
```

**Output**

| group_ids |
| --- |
| 3,4 |